# dockernize angular application

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to dockernize an angular5 application and deploy it on AWS instance.

DockerFile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8.9.4


ENV REFRESHED_AT 2017-10-01

WORKDIR /opt/
# install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
# expose server ports
EXPOSE 4200 49153

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  my-app:
    image: my/app:latest
    build: .
    ports:
        - "4200:4200"
        - "49153:49153"
```

package.json

```
{
   ...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check true --prod",
    "build": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   ...
  }
}
```

`"ng serve -H 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check true --prod"` is the command I found on Internet that can help me to run app successfully on AWS instance. The current setting is weirdly runnable after I add `"@angular/cli": "1.6.1"`,
    `"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0"` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`. I'd like to know why does it require dev-dependencies to run with `--prod`? How should I improve or correct my setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `--prod` switch only means your application will be [optimized for production](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-with---prod).

That being said `ng serve` **is not** a production-grade server (prod switch being used or not -- it only applies to output). Here is an excerpt from the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-vs-serve) saying just that:

> The ng serve command builds, watches, and serves the application from a local CLI **development** server.

Now that we know that it's a development-only server, we need to find a production server. There are many options, you could for example use [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) or [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/).

Finally, you can use a multi-stage Docker image to build and bundle your application. Dockerfile of such an image could look like this:

```
# build stage
FROM node:carbon as build

# print npm version
RUN npm -v

# copy just package.json to leverage caching
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json

WORKDIR /app

# install dependencies and cache them
RUN npm install

# copy the rest of the project
COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

# deploy stage
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: I think AWS instance provide nginx by default, do I still need to add deploy stage in dockerfile?

Comment: That step is creating an image you can then deploy using your favourite method (be it doing directly docker run or using orchestration tools like Docker Swarm, Kubernetes or Nomad). Nginx on your host is part of that system and it shares that host with other processes. If your host nginx gets compromised, so does the whole host.  One of the big selling points of containers is **isolation**. If your nginx running inside a container gets compromised, only the container gets compromised and your host *should* be safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Sorry, I'm not familiar with angular app, so after copied app build file with `COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html`, I do not need to execute any npm/ng command to run this app?

Comment: If you're unsure as to why you're using Docker, just follow their [getting started guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) which should clear everything for you.

Comment: It is run in the previous stage (build). [Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) are a bit more advanced topic, you should learn the basics first. But don't worry, it should be pretty obvious for you once you go through the getting started guide :)

Comment: Thanks, all works fine except `npm build` which returns no argument error. Luckily I managed to run it through `RUN npm run build -- --prod --environment $env`.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I wrote this dockerfile by memory without actually testing it and forgot that npm scripts have to be run with the `run` command ;) I  have already updated the answer.

Comment: the docker is runnable on AWS, but the application is still in the development version. What should I do to enable production environment?

Comment: Hi, I still can't run the image, it just hangs after I run `docker run` with image id.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Angular good enough. If you've problems with your build maybe you should ask a question about that specifically.